# Can someone explain this ( !! ) operator

Tags: javascript, typescript

Angular 6 is here already, so in short tutorial provided by [Medium](https://medium.com)
i founded this lines of code.

```
else if (!!this.day4Name && !this.day5Name && days[date] !== this.day4Name) {
        this.day5Name = days[date];
        this.day5State = data[i].weather[0].main;
        this.day5Temp = Math.round(data[i].main.temp);

      }
```

I'v try to google it, but with no results for reasonable explanation.
Can someone explain its behavior.
Thanks :)

Comment: [What is the !! (not not) operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`!!` represents a double negation, you're basically calling the [not operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Description) twice.

It's useful if you want to force a cast from any type to a boolean

e.g.

```
var somethingTruthy = {};
somethingTruthy = !!somethingTruthy //force cast to boolean
console.log(somethingTruthy); //print true
```

or

```
var somethingFalsy = "";
somethingFalsy = !!somethingFalsy //force cast to boolean
console.log(somethingFalsy); //print false
```

Comment: if day4Name is defined !!day4Name  will be evaluated to true.

Comment: To make it easy to understand, you can replace `!!` with `Boolean()`